# Which hats and pets have powers?

Tags: temple-run-2

Most hats and pets in Temple Run 2 seem to be cosmetic only, and when you equip them, it says "this hat has no powers", or similar for pets.

However, I've managed to acquire 2 hats that actually have an in-game effect, both from a Global Challenge.

[image: World Tour Hat: Boost fills 10% faster]
[image: Labor Hat: Coin Magnet lasts 10% longer]

Are there any other hats/pets with powers, and how do I get them?